# transfer json to xml in java

Tags: java, xml, json

I am trying to transfer the json to xml file but something goes wrong.

code example:

```
  String strinput= query;
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    String keyofaccount = "mykey";
    String bingApiUrlpattern = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%%27%s%%27&$format=JSON";

    String query = URLEncoder.encode(strinput, Charset.defaultCharset().name());
    String bingUrl = String.format(bingApiUrlpattern, query);

    byte[] accountkeyinbytes = Base64.encodeBase64((keyofaccount + ":" + keyofaccount).getBytes());
    String accountkeyencryp = new String(accountkeyinbytes);
    URL url = new URL(bingUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountkeyencryp);

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())))
    {
        String inputLine;

        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringbuilder.append(inputLine);
        }

        JSONObject job= new JSONObject(stringbuilder.toString());
        String xmstr = org.json.XML.toString(job);
        System.out.println(xmlstr);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

The results that i get:

```
<d><results><Description>Give your home, office and life good feng shui with expert advice from Rodika Tchi. Learn about feng shui elements, Chinese zodiac, birthstones &amp; more.</Description><Url>http://fengshui.about.com/</Url><DisplayUrl>fengshui.about.com</DisplayUrl><ID>48333f88-d9e7-4b01-913c-4b8e65e28878</ID><__metadata><type>WebResult</type><uri>https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=&apos; feng shui&apos;&amp;$skip=0&amp;$top=1</uri></__metadata><Title>Feng Shui - Expert Tips and Advice - About.com</Title></results><results><Description>Feng shui (i pinyin: fēng shuǐ) is a Chinese philosophical system of harmonizing everyone with the surrounding environment. The term feng shui literally translates ...</Description><Url>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_shui</Url>....
```

Any knows where is my problem? 
How can i get only the Description?

Comment: Could you describe what is wrong with the result? It looks like valid XML (from a quick glance)

Comment: How are we supposed to know what is wrong if you don't show us the data in original JSON format ? As I see it (but I didn't put a long analyzis effort into it) it seems to work, your output looks like XML, what do you mean by "something goes wrong" ?

Comment: for example if i search the query "where is the Louvre?". I dont get the details about location and i dont recognized it.

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.jsonToXml(json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing out the whole XML string - how do you expect it to only give a description?  To do that you would need to parse either the JSON data or the XML with something like

```
JSONArray results = job.getJSONObject("d").getJSONArray("results");
for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(results.getJSONObject(i).get("Description"));
}
```